# How can I restrict the gallery to one folder on the Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, gallery

When I go to the Galaxy S's gallery app, it shows me every JPG/PNG it can find on my SD card, including album art.

Is there a way of stopping this so it's filtered?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add an empty file called .nomedia to a directory the media scanner will ignore it.

Comment: Careful with doing this in music folders, it won't just hide the album art from the scanner, but also the music.

Answer (score 3):

adding a .nomedia file block your music from showing in your media player.

I solved the issue by deleting all of my .jpg albumart files in my music folders then letting PowerAmp download its own albumart, it makes an albumthumbs folder on your internal SD card and saves the images as non-jpg binary files so the Android media scanner doesn't pick them up.

My gallery app is clutter-free now! :)

Comment: Or embedding the album art in the music files (with a mp3 tag editor) and then deleting the album art will work too.

Answer (score 2):

Name your cover files "albumart.jpg", the gallery will ignore them.